# Pushnotification banner not showing - ios9

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios9, banner

I have one ios project with `pushnotification` enabled when adding any events from back end. All are working fine; showing `badge`, `alert` , `sound` everything ok, except '`banner`'. Banner is not showing when app is in back ground mode, i think there is nothing to code for 'Banner' from our side. This is how i registering for `pushnotification`.

```
 UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
        UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;

        UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings =
        [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

Comment: Are you running your app in the Simulator or on a iDevice? Push notifications won't show on the simulator.

Comment: Did you register your device token?

Comment: @GijsSotthewes i am running on device and i am getting every notification, i have issue on showing banner only while notification fires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the payload sending from back end crossed the size limit allowed.
As per the [official doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html) maximum size allowed is:

- For regular remote notifications, the maximum size is 4KB (4096
  bytes)
- For Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP) notifications, the maximum
  size is 5KB (5120 bytes) NOTE